# How to update a date column with sysdate including timestamp in a dynamic sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC
IS
   l_update_str   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
   l_update_str :=
      'UPDATE XX_TABLE 
             last_update_date = ''' || SYSDATE || ''',
       WHERE     1=1';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_update_str;
END;
/
```

I have tried above but it is not working. I have aslo tried using to_date(to_char(sysate)) but the time stamp is missing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I have aslo tried using to_date(to_char(sysate)) but the time stamp is missing

Makes no sense to do that.

Why PL/SQL for such a trivial task. Do it in plain SQL. The simple syntax for an **UPDATE** statement is -

`UPDATE table_name SET column_name = SYSDATE WHERE <conditions>`

To display the date column, simply use **TO_CHAR** along with proper **FORMAT MODEL**.

`SELECT TO_CHAR(column_name, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM table_name;`

For example,

```
SQL> create table t(a date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values(sysdate - 10);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t;

A
---------
25-JAN-15

SQL> update t set a = sysdate;

1 row updated.

SQL> select to_char(a, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt from t;

DT
-------------------
02/04/2015 11:29:21

SQL>
```

**UPDATE** Regarding dynamic SQL.

> 'UPDATE XX_TABLE 
>                last_update_date = ''' || SYSDATE || ''',
>          WHERE     1=1';

- Firstly, the **update syntax** is wrong. The **SET** keyword is missing.
- Secondly, you can't use SYSDATE like that in dynamic SQL.

  Since you are forming the dynamic sql, the sysdate value is appended to the SQL. The best way to test any dynamic sql is to use **DBMS_OUTPUT** and see whether the dynamic SQL is properly formed.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE TESTPROC
  3  IS
  4    l_update_str VARCHAR2 (4000);
  5  BEGIN
  6    l_update_str := 'UPDATE t
  7  SET a = ' || SYSDATE;
  8    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_update_str;
  9
 10    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_update_str);
 11  END;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec testproc;
UPDATE t
SET a = 02/04/2015 11:46:53

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So, do you see the SQL formed? The SYSDATE value is appended, instead of actually using the keyword **SYSDATE**.

So, you need to slightly change the dynamic sql.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE TESTPROC
  3  IS
  4    l_update_str VARCHAR2 (4000);
  5  BEGIN
  6    l_update_str := 'UPDATE t
  7  SET a = SYSDATE';
  8    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_update_str;
  9
 10    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_update_str);
 11  END;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec testproc;
UPDATE t
SET a = SYSDATE

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Now the above would work fine.

Comment: thanks you.. I just got it that concatenation is not required sysdate.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put systimestamp to set the timestamp in the column.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TESTPROC
IS
   l_update_str   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
   l_update_str :=
      'UPDATE test1
set name1 = SYSTIMESTAMP(6)
where 1=1';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_update_str;
END;
```

Comment: A DATE data type has both date and time values. Timestamp is an extension to date data type. No need of timestamp in OP's case.